# Launching and killing (separately) multiple isolated instances of VS Code from command line

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, electron, command-line-interface, pid

Visual Studio Code supports launching instances of itself via the `code` CLI tool. You can do something like the following:

```
$ code /Users/username/projects/dotfiles
```

And it will open VS Code w/ the appropriate project. Since VS Code is just an Electron app, this spawns a number of separate processes, with the parent process matching something like the following:

```
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron /Users/username/projects/dotfiles
```

So it seems I have a way of identifying the IDE process from its path argument. However, when I try launching another project the same way, say...

```
$ code /Users/username/projects/work
```

There is no additional process that appears with that path argument. It still only shows the first one (`projects/dotfiles`), even though there are two workspaces open in separate windows.

Ultimately, I want the ability to close/kill an individual project IDE window via bash/CLI. Is there some way of starting the 2nd VS Code project in new process such that its path shows up as a command argument in `ps`, and therefore can be killed independently of the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only viable way I could get this to work was to create a JXA/Applescript  function that took project names as an argument, and then cycle through the windows and closing them if their window name contained the project name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript -l JavaScript

run = argv => {
  system = Application('System Events')
  vscode = system.processes['Code']
  vscode.windows().forEach( window => {
    argv.forEach( projectName => {
      if(window.name().includes(projectName)) {
        window.buttons.at(0).click()  
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Created a file containing that, `chmod +x` to make it executable, and then you can just do `./closeCode.jxa ProjectName1 ProjectName2` etc. This cleanly closes the window, and if any unsaved files exist, will prompt to save them first.

Answer (score 1):

You can find association of PID with project using these few commands :

```
$ lsof | grep state.vscdb
Electron 349 username 63u REG 1,4 20480 551122 /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/9db2e998b18618ec427ec85178a324e6/state.vscdb
# 349 being PID

$ cd "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/9db2e998b18618ec427ec85178a324e6"

$ sqlite3 state.vscdb "select * from ItemTable;" | grep "debug.selectedroot.*launch.json"
debug.selectedroot|file:///Users/username/projects/dotfiles/.vscode/launch.json
# /Users/username/projects/dotfiles is project folder
```

**Update**

Try this approach :

```
lsof -R|/usr/bin/grep "^Code\\\\x20H.* /Users/username/project"
```

Third column contains pid to kill.

Comment: that did the trick, but then it exposes the fact that you can't kill an individual window in VS Code without it prompting with an error dialog. So it doesn't appear there is a way to selectively close individual windows in an orderly fashion. Ugh Electron apps are the worst.

Comment: You may take a look at https://github.com/sjitech/mac_list_windows_pids/blob/master/lswin.py to find a "proper" way to close a vscode window.